# How do I add in one single html file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to bind up the below script and form code in one html how do I go about it?
I think this code will give me a blank value when nothing gets displayed?

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
    <input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Name" id="Name" value="Full Name">

    <input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Email" id="Email" value="Email">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

and

```
$('.default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = $(this).val();
    $(this).css('color', '#746F66'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#746F66');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey  u can try this : -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $('.default-value').each(function() {
var default_value = $(this).val();
$(this).css('color', '#746F66'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
$(this).focus(function() {
    if(this.value == default_value) {
        this.value = '';
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
});
  $(this).blur(function() {
    if(this.value == '') {
        $(this).css('color', '#746F66');
        this.value = default_value;
    }
  });
});
});
 </script>
<body>
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Name" id="Name" value="Full Name">

<input type="textbox" class="default-value" name="Email" id="Email" value="Email">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: finally this one solved the my doubt.thanx for you suggestions.<script type="text/javascript">
function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }
function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
</script> 
name: <input type="text" value="enter name" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" />  .....and please upvote my answer

Answer (score 2):

Add this snippet at the end of your HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('.default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = $(this).val();
    $(this).css('color', '#746F66'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#746F66');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: could you please specify  after which tag?? like <body><form>...<form></body><script>mycode..</script> it it like that?

Comment: you can put it between `<head></head>` tag.